# Fantasy book with main character who battles giants

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a heroic fantasy novel where the main character has to fight giants of different sizes and strengths in order to stop the great evil (maybe a super powered or magic-capable storm giant?). A key plot element was the main character discovering the ability to use a special kind of breathing to grow in size so he can take on the giants. I also seem to remember individualized weapons (an axe?) playing a major role. Read this late 90s-2000, although it may have been published earlier. Any ideas what this might be?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!